# how to create loops in which create a star pyramid based on user input

Tags: java

(java) Write an application that will ask the user to enter a positive integer. Based on the user input, your program must use a loop(s) to create a pattern of stars, each subsequent row must have one less star.

input:

```
5
```

output

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
You are supposed to come up with your own solution and write the code first.

Answer (score 1):

```
void printStars(int num){
    for(int i=num;i>0;--i){
        for(int j=0;j<i;++j){
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The above code should help.

Comment: Solid implementation, but giving the code on threads where the original poster doesn't even show an attempt at researching or attempting their own question with their own effort is generally discouraged.

Comment: Got it Tim. I did not realize that the OP might have just used my code to finish his/her homework. Will keep it in mind next time onwards